# VBA Run-time Error 1004 for Special Characters in Soft-coded Vlookup Function

Tags: vba, excel

When I was trying to throw a vertical bar "|" into my vlookup function, I got a 1004 error. I am not sure where it came from.

Initially the data table looks like this:

[image: original]

And my code was like this:

```
Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(i, 2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A" & i & ",Data!$A$1:$B$" & LastRow & "," & ColmNum & ",0)"
```

Everything worked fine till the format of the data table got changed to:

[image: New Format]

So I had to throw the vertical bar "|" into my code. My new code was like this:

```
NewKey = Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(i, 1).Value & "|" & Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 2).Value
Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(i, 3).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & NewKey & ",Data!$A$1:$B$" & LastRow & "," & ColmNum & ",0)"
```

Apparently Excel 2010 did not like my codes and threw me a 1004 error. I am wondering if anyone knows a solution to this. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Why are you mixing up the sheets - Sheet1 and Data?

Comment: You add the `|` in your `NewKey` variable, but then don't use it in your formula.  Use `.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & NewKey & ",Data!$A$1:$B$"...` instead

Comment: Hi SJR. Yes I have two tabs in the workbook, Sheet 1 and Data

Comment: Hi tigeravatar. That was a mistake I made when I created this post... I already edited the code. In this way I still got the same 1004 error.

Comment: Edit: Do you mean to use this instead? `NewKey = Sheets("Data").Cells ...`.  Currently you're taking a cell from `Sheet 1` and then `|` and then a cell from `Data`...?

Comment: Hi BruceWayne. Where NewKey takes the second part of its string doesn't really matter. I tried to both Sheet 1 and Data and neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

NewKey needs to be in quotes when the formula is placed on the sheet, so you need to include the quotes in the string:

```
NewKey = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value & "|" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""" & NewKey & """,Data!$A$1:$B$" & LastRow & "," & ColmNum & ",0)"
```